# 'An unknown error has occurred.' when updating a facebook group's cover_url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

How do I successfully update a facebook group's cover_url through the graph api? No matter what I try, I get an error on the 3rd step from below:

1. Create a group by POST `/APP-ID/groups` DOCUMENTATION: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/groups#publish
2. Get the returned `GROUP-ID`
3. Using the same access_token, POST `/GROUP-ID` with `cover_url` param DOCUMENTATION: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/#update

The error I'm receiving is in the form:

```
{
   message: 'An unknown error has occurred.',
   type: 'OAuthException',
   code: 1,
   fbtrace_id: <SOME-ID>
}
```

I'm imagining there's some restriction on valid cover photos, but neither the documentation or the error give me any indication as to what that is.

I submitted a bug report to facebook in the case this is legitimately a facebook bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/425584494232936/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, this is an [issue with the facebook api itself.](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/425584494232936/)